# @PropertySource for different yaml files in Micronaut

Tags: micronaut, micronaut-aws

I'm working on Micronaut 4.1.3 and I can't use @PropertySource in getting the value of yaml file aside from application.yml / .properties.

```
@PropertySource("classpath:new.yaml")
public class TestConfig {

  private String first;
}
```

I encounter the issue:
`Incompatible types. Found: 'java.lang.String', required: 'io.micronaut.context.annotation.Property[]'`

Is there a workaround on this? TIA

Answer (score 0):

`@PropertySource` is meant to define only array of properties not the source file.

So you can do, something like

```
@PropertySource(
        @Property(name = "first", value = "1")
)
```

If you need to add the source file, you can do that by defining `environments` on @MicronautTest or `propertySources`.
Where environments will be loading dedicated `application-{env}.yml` file.

```
@MicronautTest(
        environments = {"foo", "bar"},
        propertySources = {"classpath:new.yaml"}
)
```